# Nx workspace + localstorage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, local-storage, electron, nrwl

I have an ongoing project where we use Nrwl Nx workspace to have a shared codebase among different applications (web, ionic 4, electron).
What is the proper way to implement a localstorage to the apps? Can I use @ionic/storage in all these apps, or do you recommend other libraries that are cross-platform? Should I create different implementations for the different apps/libraries? 
Thoughts and tips are welcome,
Thanks,
Yianen

Answer (score 0):

Local storage has a very minimal API. I think that the biggest overhead is in conversion of things like dates.

I'm not sure how cross-platform the ionic storage lib is but there are some others like https://github.com/localForage/localForage

It's probably best to use a single one for all of your apps though rather than mix and match.